# Core Plot : padding for the graph

Tags: ios, core-plot

Am trying to draw a simple line plot using Core Plot. 
The plot labels seem to get sliced off near the ends.

[image]

Am setting the padding this way :

```
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 25.0;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 25.0;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 25.0;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 25.0;
```

And setting the axes to nil

```
    [self.graph addPlot:plot];
    self.graph.axisSet = nil;
    self.graphHostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    self.graphHostView.hostedGraph = self.graph;
    [self.view addSubview:self.graphHostView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the `xRange` and/or `yRange` of the plot space a bit so the plot points don't fall right on the edge of the plot area. Look at the "Control Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

Comment: Sure, @EricSkroch , I'll give it a try and get back. Thank you.